# What is the syntax in D program which is the same of set.seed ( 1234)" in R

Tags: d

The "srand "is the incorrect command. This is the first time I use the D-languages. What is the code for D as set.seed in R.

```
void main() {
//srand(1234);  ????//
randInit();
auto x = RMatrix(10,1);foreach(rep; 0..1) {
printR(rep.robj);
double init = 0.0;
    foreach(ii; 0..100) {
        init = 0.5*init + rnorm();
    }
    x[0,0] = init;
    foreach(ii; 1..x.rows) {
        x[ii,0] = 0.8*x[ii-1,0] + rnorm();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on just what library you're using. You can do `rand` and `srand` if you `import core.stdc.stdlib;` but the best way is probably to use `std.random`.

Do you care about what specifically the seed is? If not, you can use the automatic one and just call some random function:

```
// Generate a uniformly-distributed integer in the range [0, 14]
auto i = uniform(0, 15);
```

or see it yoursef:

```
Random gen = Random(unpredictableSeed);
auto r = uniform(0.0L, 100.0L, gen);
```

If you do use your own `Random` object, be sure to pass it by `ref` to any function that uses it!

The `Random(unpredictableSeed)` is similar to doing `srand(time())` in other languages. You could also do `Random(1234)` to use a specific seed.

These examples come from here: http://dlang.org/phobos/std_random.html

Comment: Can't you technically just do `uniform(T1,T2)` without specifying a generator? As far as I know then `uniform(T1,T2)` will be initialized with the default random generator which is initialized with `unpredictableSeed`